# gcloud app deploy give 400 / forbidden error / cannot push img to google container registry

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to deploy .net core application from google compute vm to google app engine using `gcloud app deploy`. I get the following error

```
> WARNING: We couldn't validate that your project is ready to deploy to App Engine Flexible Environment. If deployment fails, please check the following mess
age and try again:
Server responded with code [400]:
  Bad Request Unexpected HTTP status 400.
  Failed Project Preparation (app_id='s~project-id'). Out of retries.  Last error: Temporary error occurred while verifying project: TEMPORARY_ERROR: Unabl
e to check API status
Beginning deployment of service [default]...  
WARNING: Deployment of App Engine Flexible Environment apps is currently in Beta
Building and pushing image for service [default]
Some files were skipped. Pass `--verbosity=info` to see which ones.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Could not copy [/tmp/tmpLwvVOb/src.tgz] to [us.gcr.io/project-id/appengine/default.20170118t043919:latest]: HttpError accessing 
<https://www.googleapis.com/resumable/upload/storage/v1/b/staging.project-id.appspot.com/o?uploadType=resumable&alt=json&name=us.gcr.io%2Fcasepro-v3%2Fappe
ngine%2Fdefault.20170118t043919%3Alatest>: response: <{'status': '403', 'content-length': '166', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin', 'server': 'UploadServer', 'x-g
uploader-uploadid': 'AEnB2UqprxH-2tIhsSZdGxDOtS8UnWSI29YTo4kaptNK67SWJpLVqR0zEtCAHgFyE64wj1HfCyUL5sy9z4AZkTRFYuxXfdw5TA', 'date': 'Wed, 18 Jan 2017 04:40:0
0 GMT', 'alt-svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="35,34"', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}>, content <{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
>. Please retry.
```

I have already enabled billing api, app engine admin api and storage api. Service a/c that is being used has editor rights. VM instance has been created using cloud launcher for Jenkins Bitnami package. I am trying to deploy app from command line from the vm before I configure Jenkins to do the same.

What to do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `gcloud app deploy` is trying to deploy to the project id 'project-id', which cannot be your project id.

Try setting the project like this:

`gcloud config set project MY-PROJECT-ID`

Then, retry the `gcloud app deploy` command.

If this fails, please reply with your full `gcloud` command line, and the results of these two commands:

`gcloud config list
gcloud version`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I replaced actual project-id with project-id while posting console output. But figured out that service a/c didn't have proper rights on container operations. So corrected that and it worked. However ran into another problem. Remote build output always get stuck at the following line `Updating service [default]...failed.                                                                  
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Timed out when starting VMs.  It's possible that the a
pplication code is unhealthy.  (0/2 ready, 2 still deploying).` Any help here?

Comment: I already have a version of the application on app engine with 2 vms. I can see that when `gcloud app deploy` is stuck at `Updating service..` new vms (2 in number) are visible on gui console but their status is always under refresh. Existing app engine vms as well vm from where `gcloud app deploy` is being run are in the same zone, so latency should not be a problem I guess.

Comment: @VikramChandna Since you were able to find the solution to your issue, I ask that you post it as the answer in order to help other community members who might run into the same problem. As for your new issue, this may simply be a transient timeout, where a retry would be the fix. If not it is best to report this in a [Public Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/entry) with the full '--verbosity debug' output.